# How to edit large screens in android

Tags: android

I am designing a screen using XML, and my screen is large in height, and can not displaying whole screen, so I am unable to set some properties to that controls which does not display on design screen. Is there any way to show them in Graphical Layout(I have to set properties of those control from property window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your view inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- lets suppose your root element is a LinearLayout -->
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- your content -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I want to show them on design time(in Graphical Layout). I think you gave these code to show all controls on runtime, am I right?

Comment: You are right... sorry. I haven't imagined that someone used the Graphical Layout editor instead of writing his XML layouts by hand.

Comment: No need to be sorry. You are right, I also prefer XML layout, but I am facing a problem, when I changed ID of EditText(there are 5 in my design) then R.java can not adding definition for all those EditText ( I used clean or build but problem remaining same), and when from Graphical Layout I changed ID of these EditTexts R.java creates definition (but unable to change ID for those EditTexts who does not appear). Is there other issue, which I am missing, or I am doing something wrong.